# How to get org-mode agenda clocking to look at _archive files?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

According to the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html), you can tell the agenda viewer to look at archived tasks also when generating the clock table:

```
:scope       The scope to consider.  This can be any of the following:
                  nil        the current buffer or narrowed region
                  file       the full current buffer
                  subtree    the subtree where the clocktable is located
                  treeN      the surrounding level N tree, for example tree3
                  tree       the surrounding level 1 tree
                  agenda     all agenda files
                  ("file"..) scan these files
                  file-with-archives    current file and its archives
                  agenda-with-archives  all agenda files, including archives
```

However, setting `org-clocktable-defaults :scope` as recommended to `agenda-with-archives` doesn't seem to parse any of the `filename.org_archive` files in my org directory. This can be manually toggled with `v A` in the agenda view, but it doesn't happen automatically. How can I get this behavior by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398964/2023432), an answer hints at looking through the `org-agenda-` variable list. Indeed, setting `org-agenda-archives-mode` to `t` in `.emacs` will make this the default behavior.

Comment: I don't see that information on the link you've provided.

My understanding is that your answer is correct, I just don't see how it relates to the link you mentioned.

Comment: Clocktable seems to obey the agenda view restrictions also, so this is one way to do it. That answer led me to look at the right subset of variables. I'll edit.